# wordpress page show "echo" only

Tags: wordpress

I did the backup of wordpress site from the server to the localhost . I use the BackUpWordPress . I follow all the instructions mention here

http://cool-tricks.net/backup-wordpress-to-localhost/

The first page of the website is ok . but when i click on anyother page it only show me "echo" on page and nothing more and every page has this source code

```
<html>
 <head></head>
   <body>echo </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "first page" and "any other page" here? Does it show "echo" on the "page" or the "blog post"? A sample image along with the url you are trying to open may help us?

Comment: hi thanks for the reply . First page is the main page like index.php page and if i try to access any other page ( any page ) it shows me echo

Comment: Checkout the file page.php placed inside your theme. And place the content of that file here!

Comment: Here it is 
  <?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="content-wrap-wrap">
  <div id="content-wrap">
   <?php if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  
   <div class="post">
   <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
  
    <div class="entry">
     <?php the_content(); ?> 
    </div>
   </div>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
  
   <div class="navigation">
    <?php posts_nav_link(); ?>
   </div>
  
   <?php endif; ?>
  </div><!--end of content-wrap-->
  <?php get_sidebar(); ?> 
 </div><!--end of top container-->
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a Permalink Settings issue so what i did is that

i go to Settings -> Permalink and change Common settings to Default and everything works